# Shoulders and lats give up before abs during hanging leg raises

Tags: strength, abdominals, pain, bodyweight-exercises

I've already mastered leg raises on the floor and I was advised to progress to a harder variation of leg raises which is the hanging knee raises.
The problem is that my shoulders and lats give up before my abs do. So, after about 8 reps of hanging knee raises I give up due to pain in my shoulders and lats despite keeping my shoulders tight.

I can't do pull ups yet but I'm working on it. Can the lack of strength in my lats and biceps cause this issue ? and if not, then, What causes this pain and how can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: Did you try a captain's chair leg raise? It would work the same ab muscles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Peter,

First, check your form and ensure it's good. If your form is bad, that isn't good.

Second, **Yes**, the undeveloped strength in your arms could also be a factor. *Your whole body is being supported by your arms; if they don't have enough strength, you should feel the soreness in your shoulders, lats, and arms.*

#### Solutions

- Keep working on it; the more you do it, the faster your arms will gain the necessary strength. *(Don't forget to take rests when required.)*
- Increase the strength of your arms by performing dips as well. *I highly recommend other body weight exercises too.*
- You can purchase one of these [Gut Blaster Slings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000BV0Z9). They'll support your arms while performing the exercises.

Hope this helps.